# cms/protocol: ASN.1 Error — unexpected trailing data

Tags: go, encryption, asn.1

While trying to implement a code of encryption, I got this thing in terminal

`cms/protocol: ASN.1 Error — unexpected trailing data`

What does it signify?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with CMS or exactly what you are doing, but based on the "unexpected trailing data" message and my knowledge of ASN.1, I would say the error message suggests that there was more data available after the end of the ASN.1 data, which suggests that the data does not represent what it was claimed to represent.  For example, if you have 10 bytes of data that are supposedly a PER encoding of type X, but after decoding a value of X out of that data, only 9 bytes were read, then those 10 bytes were not a PER encoding of X.